# Значение по ссылке не меняется

Tags: c++

Почему следующая программа выводит `4342`, а не `4343`, ведь `ref` - ссылка на `x`?

```
int main() {
    int x = 42;
    const int& ref = x > 0 ? x : 0;
    ++x;
    std::cout << x << ref;
}
```

Comment: Вы ссылку на что храните ? На временный объект видимо. Который тернарный оператор вернул.

Comment: особенно интересно, что будет, когда x равно 0

Comment: это я понимаю, уточню свой комментарий "что должно быть с точки зрения автора вопроса. ведь на число получить ссылку нельзя".

Comment: да, я о обычной. Видимо поэтому и было добавлено const

Comment: Я там неправильно написал, потёр поэтому комментарии. Константную ссылку `const type&` можно создать на что угодно (lvalue/rvalue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как происходит приведение к наиоблее общему типу, категория у тернарного оператора будет rvalue, и ссылку вы сохраните именно на него - на временный объект.

Попробуйте вот так - здесь будет lvalue, и всё отработает как вы того ожидаете.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    int zero = 0;
    const int& ref = x > zero ? x : zero;
    ++x;
    std::cout << x <<" " << ref;
}
```

По мотивам [статьи](https://habr.com/post/205848/).